# Android Gradle task to copy files after build

Tags: android, gradle, build

I am trying to copy a couple of files from the source tree to the directory where Gradle finally generates the apk files. The build seems to go fine but I do not seem to see the copy working. I added the following task in my modules build.gradle

```
task copySupportFiles(type: Copy){
    from 'src/main/support'
    into 'build/outputs/apk'
    include '**/.dat'
    include '**/.txt'
}

assembleDebug {}.doLast{
    tasks.copySupportFiles.execute()
}
```

Comment: `'**/.dat'`should be `'**/*.dat'` (see the additional asterisk ;)

Comment: Dang.....that was the problem!!! Please add your comment as an answer

Comment: You don't need `{}` after **assembleDebug**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @Steffen Funke in comments the error is in the additional asterisk :

`'**/.dat'`should be `'**/*.dat'`

Answer (score 4):

Your `doLast` should be placed in `afterEvaluate`:

```
afterEvaluate {
    assembleRelease.doLast {
        tasks.copySupportFiles.execute()
    }
}
```